# unable to send data from angular 2 front end to backend rest api

Tags: angular, rest, api

how to call a rest api from backend send data and get user data which is in json object

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { User } from '../_models/index';

import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }



create(user: User) {
    console.log("in create user");
 return this._http.get("http:// localhost:8082/register").map(res => 
res.json());
//    return this.http.post('/api/users', user);
}
}
```

above is angular2 service.ts code to send user data to rest

below is RegisterComponent component.ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AlertService, UserService } from '../_services/index';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id.toString(),
templateUrl: 'register.component.html'
})

export class RegisterComponent {
model: any = {};
loading = false;

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService,
    private alertService: AlertService) { }

register() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.userService.create(this.model)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.alertService.success('Registration successful', true);
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            },
            error => {
                this.alertService.error(error);
                this.loading = false;
            });
}
```

}

from above component create is calling service method create  from where i want to call post method in backend api

Below is rest api

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<Void> registrationUser(@RequestBody UserDetails user, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (user.getEmail() != null && user.getName() != null && user.getPhoneNumber() != null
            && user.getPassword() != null) {
        String name = user.getName();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        String phoneNumber = user.getPhoneNumber();
        String password = user.getPassword();
        {....
       }

                SendMail.sendMail(to, subject, msg);
                System.out.println("mail send");
                return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);

        } else
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
```

> error:
>   ERROR in src/app/_services/user.service.ts(6,57): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
>   src/app/_services/user.service.ts(28,14): error TS2551: Property '_http' does not exist on type 'UserService'. Did you mean 'http'?

Comment: error rightly mentioning Property '_http' does not exist on type 'UserService'
As you have injected http in the constructor and not _http. Have you checked correcting it.

Comment: Check browser's console did you got any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error?

Comment: Check in `spring` you have write POST method `/register", method = RequestMethod.POST` for `/register` and from angular you are calling `get` method `this.http.get` for `/register` API.

Comment: thanks for effort i am able to send data in backend rest : error was in ::  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { User } from '../_models/index';
//import {Http,Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

Comment: register() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.userService.create(this.model)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.alertService.success('Registration successful', true);
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
    }

Comment: now want to get data from rest api to front end

Comment: @hrdkisback no Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet is from the code in your first code block.

```
return this._http.get("http:// localhost:8082/register").map(res => res.json());
```

I believe you want this line to read

```
return this.http.get("http:// localhost:8082/register").map(res => res.json());
```

That seems to be what the error is complaining about. Good Luck!

Comment: yes error is on that line ,but thing is i am unable to send/get data from api in backend

Comment: i had refered this 
 code from ::http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial and want to send call to rest api

Comment: Without more detail I am not sure what the error that you are now having is. The only context I really have to go on is that there is a typo. Perhaps include what the new error you are getting is.

Answer (score 0):

**First Error**

error: ERROR in src/app/_services/user.service.ts(6,57): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http

Add HttpModule in app.module.ts

```
 import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http'

 @NgModule({
    imports:[
      HttpModule
    ]
 })
```

**Second Error**

error TS2551: Property '_http' does not exist on type 'UserService'. Did you mean 'http'?

Your Code looking wrong

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

Declared Variable name http. But you used like _http

```
 return this._http.get("http:// localhost:8082/register").map(res =>
```

so change that line this.http instead of this._http

```
 return this.http.get("http:// localhost:8082/register").map(res =>
```

I hope this solved your Error.